# Program for the given computation gives wrong output

Tags: java

Can anyone assist me in checking why the code is not giving me the right answer or where I have done it wrongly.  I will appreciate your help.
Also, below shows the computation and the code I have tried to implement. Thanks in advance.

The computation for the fand measure looks like this below

Given a data   `Si = {  0.2554,    0.4464 ,  0.3897  ,  4.2112}`
Iterate each of the value for instance

```
========================================================
Sj1 = 0.2554                                 Si1 = {0.2554}
Si1 > Sj1
0.2554 > 0.2554 = 0
Si1 = Sj2
0.2554 = 0.2554 = 1
Fand
(0   +   (0.5 * 1) )/ 1  =  0.5
==========================================================
Sj2 = 4.4464                                 Si2 = {0.2554, 4.4464}
Si2 > Sj2
0.2554 > 4.4464 = 0
4.4464 > 4.4464 = 0
Si2 = Sj2
0.2554 = 4.4464 = 0
4.4464 = 4.4464 = 1
Fand
( 0   +  (0.5 * 1) )/ 2  =  0.25
====================================================
Sj3 = 0.3897                               Si3 = {0.2554, 4.4464, 0.3897}
Si3 > Sj3
0.2554 > 0.3897 = 0
4.4464> 0.3897 = 1
0.3897 > 0.3897 = 0
Si3 = Sj3
0.2554 = 0.2554 = 0
4.4464 = 0.3897 = 0
0.3897 = 0.3897 = 1
Fand
( 1  +  (0.5 * 1) )/ 3  =  0.5  = 0.5
===========================================================
Sj4 = 4.2112                   Si4 = {0.2554, 0.4464, 0.3897, 0.42112}
Si4  > Sj4
0.2554 > 4.2112 = 0
0.4464 > 4.2112 = 1
0.3897 > 4.2112 = 0
0.42112 > 4.2112 = 0
Si4  = Sj4
0.2554 = 4.2112 = 0
0.4464 = 4.2112 = 0
0.3897 = 4.2112 = 0
0.42112 = 4.2112 = 1
Fand
( 1   +  (0.5 * 1) )/ 4  =  0.5 = 0.375
======================================================
Result
0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.375
The Fand formular in matlab code is
value = (sum( a(1:i) > a(i) ) + 0.5 * sum ( a(i) == a(1:i) ) ))/i
The Fand normal formular
Fand = ( #(si > sj) + 0.5 (si = sj)))/ i
======================================================
```

Please find the my  Java  class madion  below:

```
class madion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double data[] = {0.2554, 4.4464, 0.3897, 4.2112};
        //initialise variables
        double sam = 0;
        double sam1 = 0;
        int i;
        int j = 0;
        double m = 0;
        double n = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        //use for loop to iterate through the arrays
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            n = data[i];
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                m = data[j];
                count = 0;
                //use if statement to express the conditions and counts
                if (n == m) {
                    count++;
                } else if (m > n) {
                    count1++;
                }
            }
            double fand = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
                // System.out.println(i );
                fand = ((count1) + (0.5 * count)) / i;
                System.out.println(fand);
                //  System.out.println(count);
                //   System.out.println(count1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be `0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.375` but I am actually getting

```
0.5, 0.25, 0.1666, 0.125
```

Comment: SO it not a debugging service. You need to leanr how to use a debugger and check your code. SO it here to help you solve an identified problem

Comment: Hi Azro, I have used all the resources I can and I need help and that is why I seek your help. Can you kindly help assist me on what the problem is?

Comment: For this time ok, but careful there is many mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should **name** your variable correctly, to allow *for example* another person to understand you code quicker, then

- remove the last useless loop, which indeed was using `i` as index, so the outer loop was only doing one cycle
- reset `countEq` and `countSup` at each iteration
- divide by `n+1` as your start at 0 for array index

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] data = {0.2554, 4.4464, 0.3897, 4.2112};
    double checkVal, currentVal;
    int countEq, countSup;

    //use for loop to iterate through the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        countEq = countSup = 0;
        currentVal = data[i];
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            checkVal = data[j];
            if (currentVal == checkVal) {
                countEq++;
            } else if (checkVal > currentVal) {
                countSup++;
            }
        }
        double fand = (countSup + 0.5 * countEq) / (i + 1);
        System.out.println(currentVal + " " + fand);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three things that are not the same from the Matlab solution.

1. The i that you divide by starts from 0 in Java and on 1 in Matlab
2. There is an extra loop in there that manipulates the i value
3. The counts are reset on different levels

The code should look something like this:

```
class madion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double data[] = {0.2554, 4.4464, 0.3897, 4.2112};

        //use for loop to iterate through the arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            double n = data[i];
            int count = 0;
            int count1 = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                double m = data[j];
                //use if statement to express the conditions and counts
                if (n == m) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (m > n) {
                    count1++;
                }
            }
            double fand = ((count1) + (0.5 * count)) / (i+1);
            System.out.println(fand);
        }
    }
}
```